# jQuery Plugin - Providing an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jquery-plugins

I am currently developing a rather complex jQuery plugin. One that I am designing to be extensible. The quandary I have is how to exactly provide my users with the APIs available to them.

There are two methods that I can come up with:

1. Provide the API via an object in the global scope

   This is the method I am currently using. I do it similar to this:

   ```
   (function ($, win, undefined) {
       //main plugin functionality
       function pluginStuff() { /*...including method calling logic...*/ }

       //register function with jQuery
       $.fn.extend({ Plugin: pluginStuff });

       //register global API variable
       win.PluginAPI = { extendMe: {}, getVar: function() {} };
   })(jQuery, window);
   ```

   Unfortunately since I impliment the standard `$().plugin('method')` architecture its a little strange to have to use the jQuery method for some things and the API variable for others.
2. Provide the API via an object placed in jQuery

   I toyed with this method as well but its best practice to take up only a single slot in jQueries `fn` scope, as not to crowd the jQuery variable. In this method I would put my api variable in `$.fn` instead of the `window`:

   ```
   //register function with jQuery
   $.fn.extend({ Plugin: pluginStuff });

   //register global API variable
   $.fn.PluginAPI = { extendMe: {}, getVar: function() {} };
   ```

   I would rather not break this convention and take up two places.

---

Now that I write this I can see a third option where I assign my plugins slot in jQuery's `fn` scope to be an object:

```
$.fn.Plugin = { plugin: pluginStuff, api: { extendMe: {}, getVar: function() {} } };
```

but how well received would this be if users had to do `$('#elm').Plugin.plugin({ setting: 'value' })` to create a new instance of the plugin?

Any help or pointers would be *greatly* appreciated.

**Please Note:** I'm am not looking for a way to incorporate the API object into my plugin functionality. I am looking for a way to keep it separately modularized, but intuitively available for use/extension.

Comment: have you read the jQuery plugin authoring guide? The idea is to pass strings or string/object pairs to the plugin and let it figure out which internal method to use. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods

Comment: I'm not talking about running internal methods, as I said in my post `I impliment the standard $().plugin('method') architecture` I'm talking about an object where people can add 'plugins' designed to work with my own plugin. The object also houses utility functions useful for extending my plugin. I could do something like `$('#elm').Plugin('extend', { ... });` but I'm not sure, thats why I am asking for the experience of SO here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I eventually decided to use was registering the plugin under the `fn` namespace and the api variable under the jQuery `$` namespace. Since methods and options set operate on an *instance* of the plugin `$.fn` is the best choice.

However, the API is global and does not link to a single instance. In this case `$.fn` doesn't quite fit. What I ended up using was something similar to this:

```
(function ($, win, undefined) {
    //main plugin functionality
    function pluginStuff() { /*...including method calling logic...*/ }

    //register function with jQuery
    $.fn.Plugin = pluginStuff;

    //register global API variable
    $.Plugin = { extendMe: {}, getVar: function() {} };
})(jQuery, window);
```

now you can create an use a plugin object as expected:

```
$('#elm').Plugin();
$('#elm').Plugin('option', 'something', 'value');
$('#elm').Plugin('method');
```

and you can easily extend and access the API:

```
$.extend($.Plugin.extendMe, {
    moreStuff: {}
});
$.Plugin.getVar('var');
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could always do like

```
var plugin = function plugin() { /* do the main stuff */ };
// api stuff here
plugin.getVar = function() { };
plugin.extendMe = {};

$.fn.Plugin = plugin;
```

Or stick the extra stuff in an object that you assign to `plugin.api`.

Any way you do it, though, you're going to have to worry a bit about settings bleeding into each other.  Since everything's going to be using the same function, regardless of how you choose to set it up, you'll need a way to keep invocations of the plugin separate from one another.  Perhaps using something like, say, `this.selector` (in your plugin function) as a key into an associative array of properties, for example.  I'd normally recommend `.data()` to attach settings to individual elements, but that doesn't help much if the same element gets the plugin called for it twice.

Comment: The way I'm handling settings creep is by assigned each instance a `guid` and storing in name spaced objects keyed by the `guid`. I then set the `guid` to the element via `.data()`. I hadn't thought of modifying the function prototype though, good suggestion!

Comment: The only beef I have with this answer is that the API is global to all sliders, not specific to an instance. However placing it in the `fn` scope requires it to be called on a jQuery object, or by the fully qualified name `$.fn.Plugin`. I think I am going to put a api object in `$` so that the API can be accessed via `$.Plugin` and the plugin can be used like `$().Plugin()`.

Comment: That would work too (assuming, of course, that you pick a much more unique name than "plugin" :) ).